# how to debug dll from Microsoft Access

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ms-access, dll

I have a c++ project using visual studio 2013. It compiles a dll.

The dll is called by a Microsoft Access project.
In the Microsoft Access project, we prepare the inputs for the dll, and declares which dll to call, and calls the dll with prepared inputs.The dll returns output to Access.

My goal is to be able to step through the c++ code because I want to improve the c++ code.

Any suggestions on how may I call the dll from Access and then step through the c++ code?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164704.aspx. TL;DR version: Build a debug build of the DLL. Place breakpoints as required.  Start access project to use the DLL. From the Visual Studio main menu select Debug -> Attach To Process. Find and select Access process using the DLL (make it easy on yourself and only have one running). Click Attach button. Force Access to use the DLL. Wait for breakpoints.

Comment: Project > Properties > Debugging > Command setting.  Select MSAccess.exe from the Office install directory.  Set a breakpoint, press F5.

Comment: @user4581301 do you want to put your comment as answer ?

Comment: Hans Passant's comment is a better solution. It s a more condensed and direct version of MSalters's existing answer. Recommend you give the checkmark to MSalters and use it over the attach approach. Really wish I knew I could do that a few years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio Debugger, when debugging a DLL allows you to select the executable which is going to load that DLL. So find the MS Access executable, and specify that path. Then put a breakpoint as you would normally do, to indicate where you want to start debugging.

Comment: Need to get a debug version of dll, then make sure the Access calls the debug version dll

Comment: @Lisa: The Visual Studio Debugger will happily break into release builds, presuming of course that the breakpoint is in a bit of code that's not optimized out.  Debug versions are easier, though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to MSalters' answer, which is correct, you may start Access in the usual way, and attach to a running process. In Visual Studio, it's under menu, Debug/Attach...

If Access loads a debug build of the DLL, line breakpoints in the DLL sources will break into Visual Studio upon execution, as expected.